# WordPress index.php causing excessive processes

Tags: php, cron, wordpress, long-running-processes

Good evening, I am running a **Wordpress** blog on a shared hosting server. Recently the following lines have been appearing in my system logs and I am getting warnings from my host.

The excessive processes seem to be run on a hourly rotation, and I have checked both crontab and the cron jobs within **WordPress** using a cron review plugin. No CRON jobs are enabled on a hourly basis so I cant relate this to being a cron task running.

It always seems to be the **index.php** page also.

Can anyone advise or recommend the best way to diagnose/fix this issue?

I have tried disabling plugins but it's still happening..

```
Jun 17 21:09:03 servername lfd[5489]: *Excessive Processes* User:usersite Kill:0 Process Count:12
Jun 17 21:09:03 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:12150 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:190415 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:04 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:398 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:409864 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:04 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:17105 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:191361 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-spamshield/js/jscripts.php
Jun 17 21:09:04 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:968 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:409861 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-spamshield/js/jscripts.php
Jun 17 21:09:05 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:13502 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:408961 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:05 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:17088 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:191364 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:05 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:11205 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:537386 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-spamshield/js/jscripts.php
Jun 17 21:09:05 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:5455 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:334825 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:06 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:32005 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:536486 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:06 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:29603 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:190115 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:06 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:19129 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:191311 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
Jun 17 21:09:06 servername lfd[5489]: *User Processing* PID:11199 Kill:0 User:usersite Time:537390 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/usersite/public_html/index.php
```

Can anyone suggest or help me to stop this from happening as its stressing the server every hour :(

Comment: without seeing any code, all i can advise is to change your theme as well, if still an issue and its not your own cron job try wp supercache plugin, at least they will be hitting a low latency static copy of the index.